# Replace som text in src url on multiple images

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress

Hiy guys, I'm trying to replace "?d=80x80" with "?d=280x280" from the img src urls in different feeds i have on a page.

I tried this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( billeder ){
jQuery('.mobile.desktop img').attr('src',jQuery('.mobile.desktop img').attr('src').replace('?d=80x80', '?d=280x280'))
});
```

But it makes all the images the same image, because it changes all the src url's to the same url.

Can anyone see what i'm doing wrong?

Can i somehow make the code do it for each image individually?

Comment: What is it that you would like it to do?

Comment: The first time you use `jQuery('.mobile.desktop img')` it gets a list of images, and assumes you want to set the .attr of each one.  But inside, where you do `jQuery('.mobile.desktop img').attr('src')`, it will just return the src of the first image.

Comment: @James thank you for your reply! Do you know what i need to do differently to show each individual image and not just the first one?

Comment: @ControlAltDel i would like it not to use the first image src on all the images, and replace the text in the src url for each individual image. Hope it makes sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be a way to use .attr with a callback, but for simplicity I used .each:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( billeder ){
  jQuery('.mobile.desktop img').each(function () {
    jQuery(this).attr('src', jQuery(this).attr('src').replace('?d=80x80', '?d=280x280'))
  });
});
```